# How should I prepare my write-up for an internship program?

Tags: mathematics, research-undergraduate, internship

I am going to apply for an internship programme. It is written that the selection is based on write-up. To apply for the program I need to include an write-up with 1200 words. Also, some outlines of the project is given in the website.

But I am little bit confused. Which things I should include in the write-up? Should I include only "Why I am interested for the program?" or the part which includes what I have read earlier about the topic that I  want to pursue in the internship?

I have no idea.  Please advise me.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Include the following (in order) -

1. A very brief introduction about yourself and the motivation behind working in the field of the internship you are applying for.
2. Where you have interned/Projects done
3. The skills developed from point 2.
4. What you hope to acquire from the internship and how it will benefit you (very short sentences)
5. An ending touch.

Comment: I did not participate an intern before. So, can I replace 2) with self learning? What does an ending touch mean?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely replace that with self learning. Probably mention a book or paper you read? An ending touch meaning just a sum up of why you need this role and what makes you a great fit for it!